# Camera doesn't return Activity when checkmark is selected for captured photo

Tags: java, android

Still banging my head on the wall with the camera functionality of the App I am working on. Upon taking a picture and pressing the checkmark, the emulator camera just hangs and does not return to my Activity. Selecting the X and canceling it does return to the Activity. Really looking for some help with this. Thank you all.

Here is the `onActivityResults()` method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        /* If it's equal to my REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE var, we are all good. */
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedImage = imageUri;
            mPipePicImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }
```

Here is a helper method for creating the ImageFile

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        /* Create an image file name */
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(obj.getFilesDir(), "images");

        if (!storageDir.getParentFile().mkdir()) {
            storageDir.getParentFile().mkdir();
        }

        File image = new File(storageDir,imageFileName);

        /* Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents */
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Checking the photo permissions with this method

```
private boolean checkPhotoPermissions() {
        /* Checking if we already have permissions here.*/
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TallyActivity2.this,
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(TallyActivity2.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { /* Added this for Contacts permissions */
            /* Checking to see if we are equal to or at a higher version than Marshmallow */
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                /* System default popup box here to ask for permissions. */
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TallyActivity2.this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                /* Added this today for trying to prompt for contacts*/
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(TallyActivity2.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            /* Snapping a pic here. With this method.*/
            dispatchTakePhoto();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the `dispatchTakePhoto()` method

```
 private void dispatchTakePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(takePictureIntent); // this worked originally
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                //Log.i(TAG,photoFile+" (6) in the dispatchTakePhoto() after init");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, ""+e);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(TallyActivity2.this,
                        "com.example.bigdaddy.pipelinepipetally.fileprovider", photoFile);
                //takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to write an app that uses the camera, working with the emulator camera app is useless, IMHO. Test your app on hardware. On Android 5.0+, your use of `FileProvider` should be OK, though you will need additional code for older versions if you intend to support them. But, in general, camera apps are buggy, and you are going to encounter strange behavior on user devices as well.

Comment: @CommonsWare Duly noted. Thanks again. I will see what happens with testing on an actual device.